# Handling very large number of Tasks in memory

Tags: c#, semaphore

I am using the following pattern to perform a large number of operations (potentially millions)

```
var allTasks = new List<Task>();
var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 8);

foreach (var file in filesToUpload)
{
    await throttler.WaitAsync();

    allTasks.Add(
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await UploadFileAsync(file)
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }
        }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

However I'm concerned about accumulating a huge number of `Task` objects in the `allTasks` collection. From some diagnostic runs, I seemed to have built up about 1Gb of memory used for ~100k `Task` objects.

Is there any change that can be made to the pattern above to phase out finished tasks, but still retain the throttling effect of the overall pattern?

The only thing that I can think of myself is partitioning / batching the overall dataset so that the above code only ever operates on, e.g. 1000 elements. Is that the most appropriate approach here?

**UPDATE**

So, based on your advice Henk, I've implemented the following;

```
var uploadFileBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async file =>
{
    await UploadFileAsync(file)
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 });

foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    await uploadFileBlock.SendAsync(file);
}

uploadFileBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

This seems to work fine, and there's a relatively low memory profile the entire time. Does this implementation look OK to you?

Comment: Not a concrete answer but a) the Task.WhenAll() keeps everything in memory and b) you do a Task.Run(async void ...) to do some async I/O. Using an unnecessary thread.

Comment: The [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565531/60761) is to use  TPL Dataflow . Also read the comments below that answer.

Comment: The code keeps so many tasks in memory because of the Add() call.  Even though 100K - 8 of those tasks are already complete, not very useful.  No Clear() visible either.  Instead of WhenAll, consider to count the tasks with the CountdownEvent class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've updated the question with a code sample using TPL DataFlow - does it look like appropriate usage? Thanks for the pointers so far, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert on DataFlow but it looks OK. I would test how this handles errors, like insert an invalid filename. Also, when you are using HttpClient, see my comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343790/60761)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice - I'll take a look at all that.

Comment: It looks like it will wait for the incoming messages infinitely without `uploadFileBlock.Complete()`

Answer (score -2):

This is very similar to [another recent SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380235/c-sharp-running-many-async-tasks-the-same-time/46381108#46381108).  As with that question, an approach that might work (although I have not tested it myself) would be:

```
private async Task Test()
{
  var allTasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (var file in filesToUpload)
  {
    await WaitList(allTasks, 1000);
    allTasks.Add(UploadFileAsync(file));
  }
  await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

private async Task WaitList(IList<Task> tasks, int maxSize)
{
  while (tasks.Count > maxSize)
  {
    var completed = await Task.WhenAny(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    tasks.Remove(completed);
  }
}
```

Not only will batching like this help with memory, but it could help keep you from creating an inadvertent denial of service attach.

Other approaches might leverage the producer/consumer pattern using .Net classes such as a [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)